# New Kiwi TCMS account, full of data that is not mine

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I just made a new Kiwi TCMS account today. Until now, I have had nothing to do with the software, neither has the organization I work for. After creating an account and starting to poke around to see if this software is a good fit, I find there are hundreds of test plans and cases and builds that have nothing to do with anything I'm working on and that I did not create.

Why is there foreign data in my brand new Kiwi TCMS setup?

Do they belong to someone else, and will it cause a problem if I delete them?

If they are just sample objects, is there an easy way to wipe everything clean without deleting hundreds of objects by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify on which instance/website that account is, nor what you username is. I will assume that it is https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org.

As the name suggests "public" this is a public demo instance for everyone to play with.

If you mean a different URL/installation then you need to provide more details.

*Disclaimer: this answer has been provided by a Kiwi TCMS core team member.*

Comment: I see that was my problem, I was on the public instance. I feel rather foolish now hehe...

Thank you for your time!